# Make dataproc less verbose

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-logging

With the change of having only 5GB of logging per month we would like to limit the amount of logs we generate. Each time we start Dataproc it is very very verbose and generates a lot of logging data. Is there a way we can limit this to only warn or above messages? It looks like it's not possible to set log4j levels using `--properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik - thank you for the input.  I am PM for Stackdriver Logging.

We are delaying charging for platform logs (that are generated by the GCP services on your behalf and you do not control) until we offer you the capability to control what logs you want to keep in Stackdriver and pay for.  So there will be no charge for either Load Balancer or Dataproc logs now.  We will still charge for custom application logs generated from your code that you control as well as GCE .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Deepak, that is great to hear. This helps a lot!